# Regarding the tense of that clause after "make sure"

Tags: grammar

As for the tense of that clause after "make sure", what is the difference between present tense or future tense.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Erm.. could you clarify a bit more please.. as in what do you mean by difference b/w present and future tense for that clause?

In future it can be written as - *Make sure you submit the project on time* or *Make sure to pay up the insurance premium*

Comment: I found that we could use present tense to represent the future in the that-clause after "make sure", such as "Make sure that you attend my birthday party." or "Make sure you lock the door before you leave.". But I also found online that the future tense could also be used in this situation, such as "How to make sure you will never buy anything you won't wear". So I am wondering whether there is a difference. When should I use present tense or future tense?

Comment: Are you attempting to contrast *make sure he **is** here* with *make sure that he **will be** here*, or possibly even *make sure he **be** here*?

Comment: There is no relation between _make sure_ and the tense of its object complement; the verb in the complement clause can be either past or present tense. There is no future tense in English, but modals like _can_ or _will_ or _may_ also occur in tensed _that_ clauses, just as they do in tensed main clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Using the present tense after *make sure* can have two possible meanings:

- Future tense (usually, but not always, one-off or limited scope)
- Generic, universal time (usually unlimited scope)

If you say, “Make sure you lock the door when you go”, the most likely interpretation is the first: it is a reminder to close the door on one specific occasion in the future, when you're leaving.

If you say, “Always make sure you put on plenty of sunscreen when going to the beach”, the only possible interpretation (because of the word ‘always’) is the second: you should always put on sunscreen when going to the beach. This is not limited to a single occasion, but is generically and universally true, both in the past, present, and future.

Using a future construction after *make sure* is much rarer than the present construction. The future here has the exact same meaning as the present tense, except that it is limited to the first of the two senses listed above.

If in doubt, just use the present tense: it is both far more common and is always able to carry the meaning you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the verb which follows 'make sure' is expressed as an imperative.

'Make sure you score a goal!', is approximately the same thing as saying 'Score a goal!'.

In the imperative voice the only tense used, I would suggest, is the present. But do please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know. But I think you explanation makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not an imperative morphologically. “Make sure he eats all his vegetables” or “Make sure you are home before 10” = simple indicative present. It is semantically similar to an imperative, but I don't think that's really relevant to this question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. I see what you mean. But I'm not clear why we use the present tense. I was thinking that in French one would use the future, but I have just looked it up, and they too use the present. 'Faites en sorte que tous se passe bien'.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, "make sure" should be followed by the future when you want to say that the person prepares or is preparing everything he needs to in order not to miss doing something in the future.
For instance, he is making sure he will see you on Monday.

In that context, maybe, he is setting an alarm-clock to remind himself and writing a note about it on a piece of paper on a wall.

Answer (score -1):

I would somewhat agree with WS2 there, but the implementation of *make sure* implies another layer of reinforcement upon the other person. So saying only *Score a goal* would not be same as present tense of *Make sure to score a goal*.

So what I suggest is addition of another specific word to make it more precise :-

> Positively score a goal

Or

> Score a goal, positively.

By adding the word *positively* we add another layer of enforcement upon the other subject, or so should I say.

Comment: “Positively score a goal” is ***very*** odd English to my ear. How do you negatively score a goal?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet really? pretty sure you don't speak English much.. positive and positively are different, google for more info!

Comment: I speak English every day of my life. _Positively_ is not used with imperatives in the sense you're using it here in any kind of English I've ever been exposed to. “He positively killed ’em out there” is fine if describing someone's performance in a game, say; but I would never, ever say to him before the game, “Go positively kill ’em out there!”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You didn't look up the meaning did you?
*He positively killed 'em out there* and *Go positively kill 'em out there" have a world of difference in them.
Both mean something entirely different.

Comment: In that case, please explain what yours is supposed to mean, as well as which of the [two main senses of _positively_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/positively) fits your meaning.

Comment: In accordance with your link, it would be **1.2**, I'd like to point out here that I didn't use positively as a synonym to *make sure* but rather as a word that can be used to emphasize your main action/goal.

So both can be used together like - *Make sure you positively score a goal*

Comment: I'm with Janus. Google hits for 'really wow them' : 'positively wow them' are 697 000 : 9, indicating that most people wouldn't consider using _positively_ as an emphasizer in this way. 'He positively wowed them' is more a veridical marker, emphasising the truth of the statement rather than the degree of wowing involved. 'Positively score a goal' sounds at best youtspeak (for 'Make sure you score', and I can't find an authority licensing this usage (and it's noticeable that Invoker doesn't provide one).